# How to organize two tables on same view with one controller

Tags: angularjs, architecture, angularjs-scope

I have page with two tables. I need to make some actions with both tables, triggered outside: some functions in view controller.

So, both tables has same methods and variables and I should reload or search both tables with button and input in view controller. This is it.

What I want is to separate tables - I dont want to call reloadTable1 and reloadTable2, and use  table1Data and table2Data in scope to render it.

**First idea** was to create service for each table. But the problem was data rendering, when I use just variable to render it.
Here is example: http://plnkr.co/edit/bzgvtFzRWUDad1CR4mZV?p=preview . **Not really related, but question: why it doesnt work? I know workaround - use accessors, but I dont really want to create function per variable!** I want to use same class for 2 services, but with difference - one argument.

**Second idea** to use 3 controllers: parent and 1 per each table, reload tables with $scope.$broadcast. But I don't really like this idea: **it uses events**(I don't think it is good idea to use it in this case) and it will use additional controllers. Also, I think, it is good idea to use service here.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do if I need to share data between controllers, I use a service.

[I modified your Plunker to demostrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/844brvBIRUaMDf7IZSXZ?p=preview)

Example:

```
  <div ng-controller="main">
    {{service.data | json }}
    <button ng-click="service.query()">refresh data</button>
  </div>


  <div ng-controller="controller2">
    {{service.data | json }}
  </div>
```

Controllers and service:

```
app.controller('controller1', function($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.service = myservice;
});

app.controller('controller2', function($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.service = myservice;
});

app.service('myservice', function() {
    return {

        data: [],

        query: function() {
            for (var i in [1, 2, 3]) {
                this.data.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You could also use `$scope.$broadcast`. Or if you want to generate the event from inside the service use `$rootScope.$broadcast` (you need to inject $rootScope)